# What is the best way to write an excel file from Java?

Tags: java, excel, file-io, file-format, jexcelapi

What library would you guys recommend to write an excel file from Java?  It has to be pure Java solution, so it will work on any platform.

Thanks,
Grae

EDIT: It can't be CSV file format.  It has to have column headers, data format type, etc.

Comment: Is CSV format acceptable? It's easier and more universal.

Comment: @BalusC No, thank you, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JExcelAPI vs Apache POI, which is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763624/jexcelapi-vs-apache-poi-which-is-better) (there are no other major API's anyway). For other related questions, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+excel).

Comment: @BalusC By the way, thanks for all your help on the JSF questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution I've found for generating Microsoft document formats is the Apache POI library: http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Is it simular to JExcel?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with MS Office 2007 Excel files are saved in Office Open XML (`.xlsx`) by default.
Create such file with any content, rename it to `.zip` and look inside. It's a bunch of folders and `XML` files compressed together.

Java provides support for creating zip files using `java.util.zip`. And that's all you need.